# Можно ли сформулировать правила игры?

Tags: словообразование, филозабавы

Помню, в старых газетах были такие разделы шуточных неологизмов, что-то вроде:

- браГоразводный процесс
- поДсиделки
- сотруТничество

Не знаю, существует ли в современном мире такая игра, но как бы можно было сформулировать её правила? Например, "создать новое слово, заменяя в исходном слове (словосочетании) только одну букву" (1); или: "создать новое значение необычным сочетанием известных слов" (2)...

UPD=============== 14.08.13

Там был ещё другой способ создания неологизмов - новое толкование:

- ЗАБРАЛО - машина спецмедслужбы (которая забирала когда-то пьяных в вытрезвитель)
- ЕЛЬНИК - большой рот

Answer (score 3):

Подобием этой старой доброй игры сегодня можно, пожалуй, назвать "Загадства", в которые играют в одноимённом блоге ЖЖ по адресу http://zagadstva.livejournal.com/ Там есть и более или менее строгие правила.

Спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: >"Загадства"  
  
Восхитительно. Главное - очень точно.

Comment: По-моему, там, в ЖЖ, структурно совершенно по-другому создаются слова (да и в целом всё сложнее устроено - не просто окказионализмы, а загадки какие-то...).

Comment: Да сложнее. Здесь мы наблюдаем замены одной основы (в приставке или корне) на другую - в ЖЖ совмещение двух-трёх корней в одном слове.Но жанр загадки можно применить и к примерам из этого вопроса. Правила, конечно, нужно будет подкорректировать.

Comment: Хотя сейчас посмотрел. примеры этого вопроса вполне подошли бы в качестве загадств. Просто там, как правило, представлены более сложные примеры, но и просты не противоречат принципам игры. Посмотрите примеры на странице с правилами.
http://www.livejournal.com/userinfo.bml?user=zagadstva

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сформулировал правила подобной игры следующим образом:

*Изменить слово или словосочетание заменив (вставив, убрав) одну-две буквы, так, чтобы при сохранении отсылки к первоначальному слову (словосочетанию) у него появлялось новое значение. Например, посиделки -> подсиделки*

Во второй, предложенной вами формулировке скорей требуется создать оксюморон, *бракоразводная свадьба* вполне вписывается в критерий "новое значение с необычным сочетанием известных слов".

В первой формулировке становится необязательной отсылка к первоначальному значению, и словообразования вроде *зарядить -> нарядить*, формулировке не противоречат.

Comment: Да, правильно, "бракоразводная свадьба" сюда подходит (под определение). Становится очевидным, что в определении чего-то не хватает. Видимо, характера содержания. Так же и в первом определении: зарядить - нарядить сюда подходит, но не хватает особенности содержания.

Эта особенность - создание комического эффекта.

Answer (score 0):

У "Уральских пельменей" есть такие названия передач: "Тень знаний", "Красота спасет мымр", "Год в сапогах", "Как я провел это", "Отцы и эти"

Comment: Ещё одна особенность всплывает: в приведённых вами примерах все слова "словарные" (есть в словаре), а в старых (о которых речь в вопросе) чаще всего новое слово "нелитературно", не существует в словаре.

Ещё вспомнил. Остроумные фразы со структурой предложения (Красота спасёт мымр) очень характерны были в советское время в качестве заголовков статей в Комсомольской правде. Я даже задумался как-то: один ли специальный человек придумывает эти заголовки, или целый специальный отдел?..